# How to calculate time between values in a table?

Tags: mysql, row, calculated-columns, unique-values

thank you for having time to read my question.

I have a mysql table that logs ON and OFF actions for a sensor each in a row. Is it posible to calculate time between OFF and ON when a new row is added with value ON?

This is my table

| Time | Action | Sensor | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14:06 | OFF | 001 |  |
| 14:06 | OFF | 002 |  |
| 15:32 | OFF | 003 |  |
| 16:41 | ON | 002 | duration between OFF (14:06) and ON (16:41) |
| 17:58 | ON | 001 | duration between OFF (14:06) and ON (17:58) |
| 18:02 | OFF | 001 |  |
| 18:14 | ON | 001 | duration between OFF (18:02) and ON (18:14) |

Is this posible?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LAG() window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) if you are using MySQL 8.0:

```
mysql> select *, timediff(time, prev) as diff 
  from (
    select *, lag(time) over (partition by sensor order by time) as prev
    from mytable
  ) as t;
+----+----------+--------+--------+----------+----------+
| id | time     | action | sensor | prev     | diff     |
+----+----------+--------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 14:06:00 | OFF    |      1 | NULL     | NULL     |
|  5 | 17:58:00 | ON     |      1 | 14:06:00 | 03:52:00 |
|  6 | 18:02:00 | OFF    |      1 | 17:58:00 | 00:04:00 |
|  7 | 18:14:00 | ON     |      1 | 18:02:00 | 00:12:00 |
|  2 | 14:06:00 | OFF    |      2 | NULL     | NULL     |
|  4 | 16:41:00 | ON     |      2 | 14:06:00 | 02:35:00 |
|  3 | 15:32:00 | OFF    |      3 | NULL     | NULL     |
+----+----------+--------+--------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there's no double OFF or ON occur consequently for each sensor, each sensor will have state OFF - ON - OFF - ON.

You can use the `LEAD()`, or `LAG()` windows function to access to the next/previous time occur on the partition `sensor id`.

```
SELECT sensor_stat.*,
-- access the "next" value of record (since we're order by time in descending order, so it's the previous time that there's an action occur for this sensor) 
LEAD(time) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor ORDER BY time DESC) as last_action_occur_on
FROM sensor_stat
ORDER BY sensor_stat.time DESC;
```

give you

| time | action | sensor | last_action_occur_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18:14:00 | ON | 001 | 18:02:00 |
| 18:02:00 | OFF | 001 | 17:58:00 |
| 17:58:00 | ON | 001 | 14:06:00 |
| 16:41:00 | ON | 002 | 14:06:00 |
| 15:32:00 | OFF | 003 |  |
| 14:06:00 | OFF | 001 |  |
| 14:06:00 | OFF | 002 |  |

Now you only need to focus on the row with action `ON`, the `last_action_occur_on` will be the time of the `OFF` action occur on this sensor, simply use `TIMEDIFF(last_action_occur_on, time)` to get the duration between the last `OFF` timestamp and this `ON` timestamp.

*Read more*:
[MySQL Lead function](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-lead-function/)
[MySQL TIMEDIFF function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)